# Why is the 'if' condition not getting evaluated in the 'then' promise of the ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, callback, promise

I have an ajax call and at the end I have a 'then' promise wherein I can see that the console log returns false when there is an error but in the next line it appears that the if condition is not evaluated.

I have commented the condition in the code below as "not evaluated".

Please refer the code below:

```
    authenticate(email, password){
            const encodedEmail = encodeURIComponent(email); 
            console.log(encodedEmail);
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${encodedEmail}`,{
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(email + ":" + password)
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', true);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', false);
            }).then(() => {
                console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')); //returns true as expected
                !sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') 
               && this.props.history.push("/"); // not evaluated
            });
        }

        handleLogIn(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const email = e.target.elements.email.value;
            const password = e.target.elements.password.value;
            this.authenticate(email, password);
            this.props.dispatch(addCredentials({email, password}));
        }
```

This is my first ever hands on project, please help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no if condition.

Comment: There is one shorthand condition where I have commentated that it does not evaluates.

Comment: Why do you have the second then? If the first is not being called that means you should see an error in the catch block . If not you can handle the route change in the first then.
And if isAuthenticated is true that line will not pass as its !/negation

Comment: you are doing `false && something` which stops the evaluation at the first condition because `false && whatever` is false

Comment: I don't have access to this.props in the catch block.

Comment: @rajputsufiyaan you don't because you don't use an arrow function there and the context changes. Use an arrow function and you will have access there too or bind the outer `this`

Comment: @quirimmo Thanks for the guidance! Achieved what I wanted to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') && x` will only evaluate `x` if `sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')` evalutes to a **falsy** value (because you're using `!` to invert the value when testing it). `"true"` is not a falsy value, it's a truthy one.

There's a second issue: `sessionStorage` values are always **strings**, so you're storing `"true"` and `"false"`, both of which are truthy values, not `true` and `false`.

There's a third issue as well: `this` in your final `then` handler won't refer to what you're expecting it to refer to, you probably want to use an arrow function (or a bound function). More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

So the minimum changes version is:

1. Convert `"true"` or `"false"` back to `true` or `false`, and
2. Get rid of the `!` on your condition
3. Use an arrow function (or bound function).

I'd also suggest actually using `if`, not using `&&` for side-effects.

So for instance (note the arrow function):

```
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')); //returns true as expected
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') === "true") {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }
})
```

But if that's really the end of the promise chain, the correct way to handle it is just to move that into your earlier `then` handler (note the arrow functions):

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${encodedEmail}`,{
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(email + ":" + password)
    }
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', true);
    this.props.history.push("/"); // <==================
})
.catch((error) => { // Doesn't have to be an arrow, but if you relocate any code...
    console.log(error);
    sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', false);
});
```

If you have other things you're doing in that final `then`, though, I'd propagate the flag through the promise chain rather than going back to `sessionStorage` for it:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/${encodedEmail}`,{
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(email + ":" + password)
    }
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', true);
    return true;
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    sessionStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', false);
    return false;
})
.then((isAuthenticated) => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.history.push("/");
    } else {
        // do the other thing...
    }
});
```

...but really it makes more sense to put those two branches in the `then` and `catch` handlers (the middle example), rather than propagating a flag.

Comment: I think in your last `then` this.props will be undefined because of this context change. Maybe you intended to use arrow functions?

Comment: @quirimmo - I just used what the OP used. You're right, though, they should be arrow functions! I'll add it to the list at the top of the answer. :-)

Comment: It appears to be working now. I have removed the last then and changed the catch block to an arrow function as I only wanted to redirect when the value is false. Thanks for the explanation!. It was silly not realizing that the session will store strings.

Answer (score 5):

If `sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')` is returning true as you expected, then `!sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')` in your shorthand conditional will evaluate false, and so the bit after the `&&` won't get evaluated

Comment: I want it to get evaluated when sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') is false and it is false in the case above, still it is not getting evaluated.

Comment: @Paulpro - That won't work either, because both `"true"` and `"false"` are truthy (`sessionStorage` values are always strings).